# What are the best practices for structuring your schemas for Experience Manager?

Tags: discussion

I have recently been struggling to get a Component List editable in Experience Manager (XPM) for SDL Tridion 2013 SP1.

It turns out after recent discussions that this is not possible.

Can anyone list what they feel are the best practices for structuring your Schemas to work best for XPM? It seems like a DXA solution has many Embeddable Schemas which seem to work fine with XPM. Is this one of the best practices?

Answer (score 1):

One thing that I've started doing since implementing XPM is to put any metadata on the Page, rather than the Structure Group.

Although you can't edit the Page Metadata inline, having it on the Page allows editors to 'Open in form view' to edit it.

**Side note:** *Maybe one for the 'ideas' page, but it would be nice to have a 'Go to location' button within the XPM interface.*

Comment: Thanks Jon. Nice bit of info.

Comment: Jon, we monitor new ideas posted here: https://community.sdl.com/solutions/content-management/tridion/sdl_web_ideas/i/sdl_web_general_suggestions - this "go to location" suggestion sounds interesting, care to post it there and expand a bit on how you think it should work?

Comment: Thank @NunoLinhares. I've added this under the heading **Add a 'Go to location' button into the XPM interface when viewing pages**. It's currently under review.